# Termios/Xterm line editor for APL interpreter

Tags: c, console, interpreter, unix, unicode

As an interesting sub-part of an interpreter -- just the *Read* part of the REPL -- I present my raw-mode line-oriented editor that I intend to use for my APL interpreter. (The *Eval* part has been posted for review in [comp.lang.c](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.c/7NeTMCbl9zM/discussion).) It defines a large character-translation table to coordinate the input-form/internal-rep/output-form for "normal" keyboards and an "alternate" keyboard accessed with the <kbd>alt</kbd> key (also toggle-able with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>). The alternate keyboard is patterned after the classic APL keyboards I've seen.

> ```
> ·¨¯<=>≠¹²_÷
> ◆1234567890­×
> QWERTYUIOP→£≠
> ?⍵∈⍴∾↑↓⍳○⋆←]\
> ASDFGHJKL:"
> ⍺⌈⌊_±∆∘'⎕º´
> ZXCVBNM«»¿
> ⊂⊃∩∪⊥⊤∣¶·÷
> ```

Algorithmically, it's quite abominable due to linear searching on every key-stroke. But I do have a symbol-table available that will likely speed this up, when measurements deem it necessary.

It sets up a `specialtty()` mode using termios settings and VT220 charset codes. The VT codes are largely a crutch until I better understand how to interface Unicode more directly with Xterm.

**ed.h:**

```
/* the raw-mode editor */

/* setup special raw terminal mode and save restore variable */
void specialtty();

/* use restore variable to reset terminal to normal mode */
void restoretty();

/* get input line as int array of internal codes */
int *get_line(char *prompt, int **bufref, int *len);
```

**ed.c:**

```
#include<errno.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<termios.h>
#include<unistd.h>

/* Special ascii control-code macros
   */
#define ESC(x) "\x1b" #x
#define ESCCHR '\x1b'
#define CTL(x) (x-64)
#define EOT 004
#define DEL 127
#define MODE1(x) (x|1<<7)



/*
   The Alphabet table defines the input and output of character data
   (including non-ascii APL symbols).
 */
/* ALPHA_##NAME  base  ext input  output
   ALPHA_##NAME indexes the table
   base is the internal representation, ideally the UCS4 code
   ext corresponds to 'mode' in get_line 0==normal_keyboard 1==alt_keyboard
   input and output are defined as strings so they can extend to multichar
   input- and output- translations.
   currently only output uses strings. only the first char of *input
   is currently matched.
 */
#define ALPHATAB(_) \
    _( SPACE, ' ', 0, " ", " " ) \
    _( a, 'a', 0, "a", "a" ) /* basic latin alphabet */ \
    _( b, 'b', 0, "b", "b" ) \
    _( c, 'c', 0, "c", "c" ) \
    _( d, 'd', 0, "d", "d" ) \
    _( e, 'e', 0, "e", "e" ) \
    _( f, 'f', 0, "f", "f" ) \
    _( g, 'g', 0, "g", "g" ) \
    _( h, 'h', 0, "h", "h" ) \
    _( i, 'i', 0, "i", "i" ) \
    _( j, 'j', 0, "j", "j" ) \
    _( k, 'k', 0, "k", "k" ) \
    _( l, 'l', 0, "l", "l" ) \
    _( m, 'm', 0, "m", "m" ) \
    _( n, 'n', 0, "n", "n" ) \
    _( o, 'o', 0, "o", "o" ) \
    _( p, 'p', 0, "p", "p" ) \
    _( q, 'q', 0, "q", "q" ) \
    _( r, 'r', 0, "r", "r" ) \
    _( s, 's', 0, "s", "s" ) \
    _( t, 't', 0, "t", "t" ) \
    _( u, 'u', 0, "u", "u" ) \
    _( v, 'v', 0, "v", "v" ) \
    _( w, 'w', 0, "w", "w" ) \
    _( x, 'x', 0, "x", "x" ) \
    _( y, 'y', 0, "y", "y" ) \
    _( z, 'z', 0, "z", "z" ) \
    _( A, 'A', 0, "A", "A" ) \
    _( B, 'B', 0, "B", "B" ) \
    _( C, 'C', 0, "C", "C" ) \
    _( D, 'D', 0, "D", "D" ) \
    _( E, 'E', 0, "E", "E" ) \
    _( F, 'F', 0, "F", "F" ) \
    _( G, 'G', 0, "G", "G" ) \
    _( H, 'H', 0, "H", "H" ) \
    _( I, 'I', 0, "I", "I" ) \
    _( J, 'J', 0, "J", "J" ) \
    _( K, 'K', 0, "K", "K" ) \
    _( L, 'L', 0, "L", "L" ) \
    _( M, 'M', 0, "M", "M" ) \
    _( N, 'N', 0, "N", "N" ) \
    _( O, 'O', 0, "O", "O" ) \
    _( P, 'P', 0, "P", "P" ) \
    _( Q, 'Q', 0, "Q", "Q" ) \
    _( R, 'R', 0, "R", "R" ) \
    _( S, 'S', 0, "S", "S" ) \
    _( T, 'T', 0, "T", "T" ) \
    _( U, 'U', 0, "U", "U" ) \
    _( V, 'V', 0, "V", "V" ) \
    _( W, 'W', 0, "W", "W" ) \
    _( X, 'X', 0, "X", "X" ) \
    _( Y, 'Y', 0, "Y", "Y" ) \
    _( Z, 'Z', 0, "Z", "Z" ) \
    /* ALPHA_NAME      base ext input output */ \
    _( ONE,             '1',  0, "1", "1" ) /* ascii digits */ \
    _( TWO,             '2',  0, "2", "2" ) \
    _( THREE,           '3',  0, "3", "3" ) \
    _( FOUR,            '4',  0, "4", "4" ) \
    _( FIVE,            '5',  0, "5", "5" ) \
    _( SIX,             '6',  0, "6", "6" ) \
    _( SEVEN,           '7',  0, "7", "7" ) \
    _( EIGHT,           '8',  0, "8", "8" ) \
    _( NINE,            '9',  0, "9", "9" ) \
    _( ZERO,            '0',  0, "0", "0" ) \
    _( ONE1,            '1',  1, "1", "1" ) /* accept same digits in alt mode */ \
    _( TWO1,            '2',  1, "2", "2" ) \
    _( THREE1,          '3',  1, "3", "3" ) \
    _( FOUR1,           '4',  1, "4", "4" ) \
    _( FIVE1,           '5',  1, "5", "5" ) \
    _( SIX1,            '6',  1, "6", "6" ) \
    _( SEVEN1,          '7',  1, "7", "7" ) \
    _( EIGHT1,          '8',  1, "8", "8" ) \
    _( NINE1,           '9',  1, "9", "9" ) \
    _( ZERO1,           '0',  1, "0", "0" ) \
    _( PLUS,            '+',  0, "+", "+" ) /* ascii punctuation */ \
    _( MINUS,           '-',  0, "-", "-" ) \
    _( EQUAL,           '=',  0, "=", "=" ) \
    _( UNDERSCORE,      '_',  0, "_", "_" ) \
    _( LBRACE,          '{',  0, "{", "{" ) \
    _( RBRACE,          '}',  0, "}", "}" ) \
    _( PIPE,            '|',  0, "|", "|" ) \
    _( LBRACKET,        '[',  0, "[", "[" ) \
    _( RBRACKET,        ']',  0, "]", "]" ) \
    _( BACKSLASH,       '\\', 0, "\\", "\\" ) \
    _( COLON,           ':',  0, ":", ":" ) \
    _( SEMICOLON,       ';',  0, ";", ";" ) \
    _( QUOTE,           '\'', 0, "'", "'" ) \
    _( DBLQUOTE,        '"',  0, "\"", "\"" ) \
    _( COMMA,           ',',  0, ",", "," ) \
    _( PERIOD,          '.',  0, ".", "." ) \
    _( SLASH,           '/',  0, "/", "/" ) \
    _( LANG,            '<',  0, "<", "<" ) \
    _( RANG,            '>',  0, ">", ">" ) \
    _( QUESTION,        '?',  0, "?", "?" ) \
    _( TILDE,           '~',  0, "~", "~" ) \
    _( BACKQUOTE,       '`',  0, "`", "`" ) \
    _( EXCL,            '!',  0, "!", "!" ) \
    _( AT,              '@',  0, "@", "@" ) \
    _( HASH,            '#',  0, "#", "#" ) \
    _( DOLLAR,          '$',  0, "$", "$" ) \
    _( PERCENT,         '%',  0, "%", "%" ) \
    _( CARET,           '^',  0, "^", "^" ) \
    _( AMPERSAND,       '&',  0, "&", "&" ) \
    _( STAR,            '*',  0, "*", "*" ) \
    _( LPAREN,          '(',  0, "(", "(" ) \
    _( RPAREN,          ')',  0, ")", ")" ) \
    /* ALPHA_NAME base      ext input output */ \
    /*_( PLUSMINUS, MODE1('g'), 1, "g", ESC(n)"g""\xE" ) */\
    /* xterm alt graphics chars */ \
    _( TWODOTS,   0x00a8, 1, "!", ESC(o)"(""\xE" ) \
    _( DIAERESIS, MODE1('!'), 1, "!", /*U+00a8*/ /*"\xc2"*/"\xa8" ) \
    _( HIMINUS,   0x00af, 1, "@", ESC(o)"/""\xE" ) \
    _( MACRON,    MODE1('@'), 1, "@", /*U+00af*/ /*"\xc2"*/"\xaf" ) \
    _( NOTEQUAL,  MODE1('|'), 1, "|", ESC(n)"|""\xE" ) \
    _( LESS,            '<',  1, "#", "<" ) \
    _( LESSEQ,    0x2264, 1, "$", /*U+2264*/ "\xe2\x89\xa4") \
    _( LESSEQUAL, MODE1('$'), 1, "$", ESC(n)"y""\xE" ) \
    _( EQALT,           '=',  1, "%", "=" ) \
    _( MOREEQ,    0x2265, 1, "^", /*U+2265*/ "\xe2\x89\xa5") \
    _( MOREEQUAL, MODE1('^'), 1, "^", ESC(n)"z""\xE" ) \
    _( MORE,            '>',  1, "&", ">" ) \
    _( EQSLASH,   MODE1('*'), 1, "*", ESC(n)"|""\xE" ) \
    _( QUEST,           '?',  1, "q", "?" ) \
    _( OMEGA,     0x2375, 1, "w", /*U+2375*/ "\xe2\x8d\xb5" ) \
    _( EPSILON,   0x2208, 1, "e", /*U+2208*/ "\xe2\x88\x88" ) \
    _( RHO,       0x2374, 1, "r", /*U+2374*/ "\xe2\x8d\xb4" ) \
    _( TILDEOP,   0x223c, 1, "t", /*U+223c*/ "\xe2\x88\xbe" ) \
    _( UPARROW,   0x2191, 1, "y", /*U+2191*/ "\xe2\x86\x91" ) \
    _( DNARROW,   0x2193, 1, "u", /*U+2193*/ "\xe2\x86\x93" ) \
    _( IOTA,      0x2373, 1, "i", /*U+2373*/ "\xe2\x8d\xb3" ) \
    _( CIRCLE,    0x25cb, 1, "o", /*U+25cb*/ "\xe2\x97\x8b" ) \
    _( STAROP,    0x22c6, 1, "p", /*U+22c6*/ "\xe2\x8b\x86" ) \
    _( LTARROW,   0x2190, 1, "[", /*U+2190*/ "\xe2\x86\x90" ) \
    _( RTARROW,   0x2192, 1, "{", /*U+2192*/ "\xe2\x86\x92" ) \
    _( ALPHA,     0x237a, 1, "a", /*U+237a*/ "\xe2\x8d\xba" ) \
    _( LEFTCEIL,  0x2308, 1, "s", /*U+2308*/ "\xe2\x8c\x88" ) \
    _( LEFTFLOOR, 0x230a, 1, "d", /*U+230a*/ "\xe2\x8c\x8a" ) \
    _( UNDBAR2,         '_',  1, "f", "_" ) \
    _( NABLA,     0x2207, 1, "g", /*U+2207*/ "\xe2\x88\x87" ) \
    _( INCREMENT, 0x2206, 1, "h", /*U+2206*/ "\xe2\x88\x86" ) \
    _( RING,      0x2218, 1, "j", /*U+2218*/ "\xe2\x88\x98" ) \
    _( KWOTE,          '\'',  1, "k", "'" ) \
    _( QUAD,      0x2395, 1, "l", /*U+2395*/ "\xe2\x8e\x95" ) \
    _( SUBSET,    0x2282, 1, "z", /*U+2282*/ "\xe2\x8a\x82" ) \
    _( SUPERSET,  0x2283, 1, "x", /*U+2283*/ "\xe2\x8a\x83" ) \
    _( CAP,       0x2229, 1, "c", /*U+2229*/ "\xe2\x88\xa9" ) \
    _( CUP,       0x222a, 1, "v", /*U+222a*/ "\xe2\x88\xaa" ) \
    _( UPTACK,    0x22a5, 1, "b", /*U+22a5*/ "\xe2\x8a\xa5" ) \
    _( DNTACK,    0x22a4, 1, "n", /*U+22a4*/ "\xe2\x8a\xa4" ) \
    _( DIVIDES,   0x2223, 1, "m", /*U+2223*/ "\xe2\x88\xa3" ) \
    _( DOT,       MODE1('~'), 1, "~", ESC(n)"~""\xE" ) \
    _( DIAMOND,   MODE1('`'), 1, "`", ESC(n)"`""\xE" ) \
    _( PI,        MODE1('{'), 1, "{", ESC(n)"{""\xE" ) \
    _( POUND,     MODE1('}'), 1, "}", ESC(n)"}""\xE" ) \
    _( EURO,      MODE1('e'), 1, "e", "\xe2\x82\xac" ) \
    _( CENT,      MODE1('e'), 1, "e", ESC(o)"\"""\xE" ) \
    _( YEN,       MODE1('d'), 1, "d", ESC(o)"%""\xE" ) \
    _( HBAR0,     MODE1('o'), 1, "o", ESC(n)"o""\xE" ) \
    _( HBAR1,     MODE1('p'), 1, "p", ESC(n)"p""\xE" ) \
    _( HBAR3,     MODE1('q'), 1, "q", ESC(n)"q""\xE" ) \
    _( HBAR4,     MODE1('r'), 1, "r", ESC(n)"r""\xE" ) \
    _( HBAR5,     MODE1('s'), 1, "s", ESC(n)"s""\xE" ) \
    _( GRAYBOX,   MODE1('a'), 1, "a", ESC(n)"a""\xE" ) \
    _( DEGREE,    MODE1('f'), 1, "f", ESC(n)"f""\xE" ) \
    _( HT,        '\x9', 0, "\t", ESC(n)"b""\xE" ) \
    _( NL,        '\xa', 0, "\n", ESC(n)"h""\xE" ) \
    _( LF,        '\xa', 0, "\n", ESC(n)"e""\xE" ) \
    _( VT,        '\xb', 0, "\v", ESC(n)"i""\xE" ) \
    _( FF,        '\xc', 0, "\f", ESC(n)"c""\xE" ) \
    _( CR,        '\xd', 0, "\r", ESC(n)"d""\xE" ) \
    _( JUNCL,     MODE1('m'), 1, "m", ESC(n)"m""\xE" ) \
    _( JUNCJ,     MODE1('j'), 1, "j", ESC(n)"j""\xE" ) \
    _( JUNCK,     MODE1('k'), 1, "k", ESC(n)"k""\xE" ) \
    _( JUNCR,     MODE1('l'), 1, "l", ESC(n)"l""\xE" ) \
    _( VBAR,      MODE1('x'), 1, "x", ESC(n)"x""\xE" ) \
    _( JUNCF,     MODE1('t'), 1, "t", ESC(n)"t""\xE" ) \
    _( JUNC3,     MODE1('u'), 1, "u", ESC(n)"u""\xE" ) \
    _( JUNCT,     MODE1('w'), 1, "w", ESC(n)"n""\xE" ) \
    _( JUNCM,     MODE1('n'), 1, "n", ESC(n)"w""\xE" ) \
    _( JUNCW,     MODE1('b'), 1, "b", ESC(n)"v""\xE" ) \
    /* ALPHA_NAME base       ext input output */ \
    _( INVEXCL,   MODE1('!'), 1, "!", ESC(o)"!""\xE" ) /* "uk" chars patch */ \
    _( INVQUEST,  MODE1('?'), 1, "?", ESC(o)"?""\xE" ) \
    _( GUILLEFT,  MODE1('<'), 1, "<", ESC(o)"+""\xE" ) \
    _( GUILRIGHT, MODE1('>'), 1, ">", ESC(o)";""\xE" ) \
    _( COMPL,     MODE1('^'), 1, "^", ESC(o)",""\xE" ) \
    _( TIMES,     MODE1('='), 1, "=", ESC(o)"W""\xE" ) \
    _( DIVIDE,    MODE1('/'), 1, "/", ESC(o)"w""\xE" ) \
    _( CDOT,      MODE1('.'), 1, ".", ESC(o)"7""\xE" ) \
    _( HYPHEN,    MODE1('-'), 1, "-", ESC(o)"-""\xE" ) \
    _( BUTTON,    MODE1('i'), 1, "i", ESC(o)"$""\xE" ) \
    _( SECTION,   MODE1('h'), 1, "h", ESC(o)"'""\xE" ) \
    _( PRIME,     MODE1('\''), 1, "'", ESC(o)"4""\xE" ) \
    _( CIRCC,     MODE1('c'), 1, "c", ESC(o)")""\xE" ) \
    _( ZEROSLASH, MODE1('v'), 1, "v", ESC(o)"X""\xE" ) \
    _( OBAR,      MODE1(';'), 1, ";", ESC(o)":""\xE" ) \
    /* ALPHA_NAME base       ext input output */ \
    _( PARAGRAPH, MODE1(','), 1, ",", ESC(o)"6""\xE" ) \
    _( BARA,      MODE1('@'), 1, "@", ESC(o)"*""\xE" ) \
    _( CIRCR,     MODE1('#'), 1, "#", ESC(o)".""\xE" ) \
    _( MU,        MODE1('$'), 1, "$", ESC(o)"5""\xE" ) \
    _( COLONBAR,  MODE1('+'), 1, "+", ESC(o)"w""\xE" ) \
    _( DEL,       MODE1('&'), 1, "&", ESC(o)"P""\xE" ) \
    _( SUPONE,    MODE1('('), 1, "(", ESC(o)"9""\xE" ) \
    _( SUPTWO,    MODE1(')'), 1, ")", ESC(o)"2""\xE" ) \
    /*_( SUPTHREE,  MODE1('+'), 1, "+", ESC(o)"1""\xE" )*/ \
    _( a1, 'a', 1, "a", "a" ) /* fallback: basic latin alphabet */ \
    _( b1, 'b', 1, "b", "b" ) \
    _( c1, 'c', 1, "c", "c" ) \
    _( d1, 'd', 1, "d", "d" ) \
    _( e1, 'e', 1, "e", "e" ) \
    _( f1, 'f', 1, "f", "f" ) \
    _( g1, 'g', 1, "g", "g" ) \
    _( h1, 'h', 1, "h", "h" ) \
    _( i1, 'i', 1, "i", "i" ) \
    _( j1, 'j', 1, "j", "j" ) \
    _( k1, 'k', 1, "k", "k" ) \
    _( l1, 'l', 1, "l", "l" ) \
    _( m1, 'm', 1, "m", "m" ) \
    _( n1, 'n', 1, "n", "n" ) \
    _( o1, 'o', 1, "o", "o" ) \
    _( p1, 'p', 1, "p", "p" ) \
    _( q1, 'q', 1, "q", "q" ) \
    _( r1, 'r', 1, "r", "r" ) \
    _( s1, 's', 1, "s", "s" ) \
    _( t1, 't', 1, "t", "t" ) \
    _( u1, 'u', 1, "u", "u" ) \
    _( v1, 'v', 1, "v", "v" ) \
    _( w1, 'w', 1, "w", "w" ) \
    _( x1, 'x', 1, "x", "x" ) \
    _( y1, 'y', 1, "y", "y" ) \
    _( z1, 'z', 1, "z", "z" ) \
    _( A1, 'A', 1, "A", "A" ) \
    _( B1, 'B', 1, "B", "B" ) \
    _( C1, 'C', 1, "C", "C" ) \
    _( D1, 'D', 1, "D", "D" ) \
    _( E1, 'E', 1, "E", "E" ) \
    _( F1, 'F', 1, "F", "F" ) \
    _( G1, 'G', 1, "G", "G" ) \
    _( H1, 'H', 1, "H", "H" ) \
    _( I1, 'I', 1, "I", "I" ) \
    _( J1, 'J', 1, "J", "J" ) \
    _( K1, 'K', 1, "K", "K" ) \
    _( L1, 'L', 1, "L", "L" ) \
    _( M1, 'M', 1, "M", "M" ) \
    _( N1, 'N', 1, "N", "N" ) \
    _( O1, 'O', 1, "O", "O" ) \
    _( P1, 'P', 1, "P", "P" ) \
    _( Q1, 'Q', 1, "Q", "Q" ) \
    _( R1, 'R', 1, "R", "R" ) \
    _( S1, 'S', 1, "S", "S" ) \
    _( T1, 'T', 1, "T", "T" ) \
    _( U1, 'U', 1, "U", "U" ) \
    _( V1, 'V', 1, "V", "V" ) \
    _( W1, 'W', 1, "W", "W" ) \
    _( X1, 'X', 1, "X", "X" ) \
    _( Y1, 'Y', 1, "Y", "Y" ) \
    _( Z1, 'Z', 1, "Z", "Z" ) \
    _( PLUS1,            '+',  1, "+", "+" ) /* fallback: ascii punctuation */ \
    _( MINUS1,           '-',  1, "-", "-" ) \
    _( EQUAL1,           '=',  1, "=", "=" ) \
    _( UNDERSCORE1,      '_',  1, "_", "_" ) \
    _( LBRACE1,          '{',  1, "{", "{" ) \
    _( RBRACE1,          '}',  1, "}", "}" ) \
    _( PIPE1,            '|',  1, "|", "|" ) \
    _( LBRACKET1,        '[',  1, "[", "[" ) \
    _( RBRACKET1,        ']',  1, "]", "]" ) \
    _( BACKSLASH1,       '\\', 1, "\\", "\\" ) \
    _( COLON1,           ':',  1, ":", ":" ) \
    _( SEMICOLON1,       ';',  1, ";", ";" ) \
    _( QUOTE1,           '\'', 1, "'", "'" ) \
    _( DBLQUOTE1,        '"',  1, "\"", "\"" ) \
    _( COMMA1,           ',',  1, ",", "," ) \
    _( PERIOD1,          '.',  1, ".", "." ) \
    _( SLASH1,           '/',  1, "/", "/" ) \
    _( LANG1,            '<',  1, "<", "<" ) \
    _( RANG1,            '>',  1, ">", ">" ) \
    _( QUESTION1,        '?',  1, "?", "?" ) \
    _( TILDE1,           '~',  1, "~", "~" ) \
    _( BACKQUOTE1,       '`',  1, "`", "`" ) \
    _( EXCL1,            '!',  1, "!", "!" ) \
    _( AT1,              '@',  1, "@", "@" ) \
    _( HASH1,            '#',  1, "#", "#" ) \
    _( DOLLAR1,          '$',  1, "$", "$" ) \
    _( PERCENT1,         '%',  1, "%", "%" ) \
    _( CARET1,           '^',  1, "^", "^" ) \
    _( AMPERSAND1,       '&',  1, "&", "&" ) \
    _( STAR1,            '*',  1, "*", "*" ) \
    _( LPAREN1,          '(',  1, "(", "(" ) \
    _( RPAREN1,          ')',  1, ")", ")" ) \
    /* ALPHA_NAME base      ext input output */ \
    _( NULLCHAR, 0, 0, 0, 0 )
#define ALPHATAB_ENT(a,...) {__VA_ARGS__},
struct alpha{
    int base;int ext;char*input;char*output;
}alphatab[]={ALPHATAB(ALPHATAB_ENT)};
#define ALPHATAB_NAME(a,...) ALPHA_ ## a ,
enum alphaname { ALPHATAB(ALPHATAB_NAME) };
    /* NB. ALPHA_NAME!=alphatab[ALPHA_NAME].base */
```

...breaking this file here, so the functions are less hidden by the table...

```
int inputtobase(int c, int mode){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<(sizeof alphatab/sizeof*alphatab);i++)
        if (c==*alphatab[i].input && mode==alphatab[i].ext)
            return alphatab[i].base;
    return mode? MODE1(c): c;
}

char *basetooutput(int c){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<(sizeof alphatab/sizeof*alphatab);i++)
        if (c==alphatab[i].base)
            return alphatab[i].output;
    return "";
}

struct termios tm;

void specialtty(){

    fputs(ESC()")B",stdout); // set G1 charset to B:usascii
    fputs(ESC(*0),stdout); // set G2 to 0:line drawing ESC(n)
    fputs(ESC(+A),stdout); // set G3 to A:"uk" accented ESC(o)
    fputc(CTL('N'),stdout); // select G1 charset
                            // ESC(n): select G2
                            // ESC(o): select G3

    tcgetattr(0,&tm);

    struct termios tt=tm;
    tt.c_iflag |= IGNPAR; //ignore parity errors
    tt.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | PARMRK | ISTRIP | ICRNL | IXON | IXANY | IXOFF); //ignore special characters
    tt.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHOE | ECHOK | ECHONL | ICANON /*| ISIG*/ ); // non-canonical mode, no echo, no kill
    //tt.c_lflag &= ~IEXTEN;
    tt.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
    tt.c_cflag |= CS8;
    //tt.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; // disable special output processing
    tt.c_oflag |= OPOST;
    tt.c_cc[VMIN] = 1; // min chars to read
    tt.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; // timeout
    //cfmakeraw(&tt);
    if (tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&tt) == -1)
        perror("tcsetattr");

}

void restoretty(){
    tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&tm);
}

int *get_line(char *prompt, int **bufref, int *len){
    int mode = 0;
    int tmpmode = 0;
    int *p;

    if (prompt) fputs(prompt,stdout);
    if (!*bufref) *bufref = malloc((sizeof**bufref) * (*len=256));
    p = *bufref;

    while(1){
        int c;
        if (p-*bufref>*len){
            int *t = realloc(*bufref,(sizeof**bufref) * (*len*=2));
            if (t) *bufref = t;
            else { *len/=2; return NULL; }
        }
        //puts(">");
        while(1){
            c = fgetc(stdin);
            if (c==EOF){
                if (ferror(stdin)){
                    perror("fgetc");
                    clearerr(stdin);
                    continue;
                } else
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }

        //printf("%d\n", c);
        switch(c){
        case EOF:
        case EOT: if (p==*bufref) goto err;
                  break;
        case ESCCHR:
                c = fgetc(stdin);
                switch(c){
                default:
                    tmpmode = 1;
                    goto storechar;
                    break;
                }
                break;
        case '\r':
        case '\n':
                fputc('\r', stdout);
                fputc('\n', stdout);
                *p++ = c;
                goto breakwhile;
        case CTL('N'):
                mode = !mode;
                tmpmode = 0;
                break;
        case CTL('U'):
                while(p>*bufref){
                    fputs("\b \b", stdout);
                    --p;
                }
                tmpmode = 0;
                break;
        case '\b':
        case DEL:
                fputs("\b \b", stdout);
                if (p!=*bufref) --p;
                break;
        default:
storechar:
                c = inputtobase(c,mode|tmpmode);
                *p++ = c;
                tmpmode = 0;
                fputs(basetooutput(c), stdout);
                break;
        }
    }
breakwhile:
    *p++ = 0;
    *len = p-*bufref;
err:
    return p==*bufref?NULL:*bufref;
}
```

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "ed.h"
#include "io.h"
#include "st.h"

symtab env;

int main() {
    int *buf = NULL;
    char *prompt = "\t";
    int n;

    env = makesymtab(10);

    if (isatty(fileno(stdin))) specialtty();

    while(get_line(prompt, &buf, &n)){
        int i;
        //puts(buf);
        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
            printf("%04x ", buf[i]);
    }

    if (isatty(fileno(stdin))) restoretty();
    return 0;
}
```

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/tree/9bd785df7eff3ef2b9739d73198da99ac66ed998)

### Questions

Unlike the previous 2 modules submitted for review ([1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98838/utf-8-encoding-decoding) [2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114243/unicode-capable-symbol-table-n-way-search-tree-with-hash-buckets)), this one does not currently have unit tests. Do I need them? How shall I mock-up the user with this weird terminal interface on the input? What things do I need to test?

Is there a better way to interface with the terminal altogether? I don't want to use `ncurses` because I don't want to clear the screen. Is there a layer lower than curses but higher than termios? Can I access all of APL's characters via utf8 and dispense with the VT220 codes altogether?

Where do I even begin with the Windows port?

---

Update. Detection of arrow-keys and other specials has been [added to the GitHub repo](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/tree/master/olmec)
), but not here. It is based on the technique revealed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824604/how-do-you-read-the-arrow-keys).

Comment: @200_success Should I be posting specific commits for all my related links?

Comment: I think so. It's relatively difficult to figure out which commit represents the state of the project at the time the question was posted. In contrast, anyone can easily skip to the HEAD of the master branch if they want to see the current state of the project. (If the entire codebase is embedded in the question, then it makes little difference either way.)

Comment: Makes sense. Wilco.

Answer (score 1):

Rather that all the tedious character translation stuff, apart from being inefficient is it complicates real interaction with Unicode encoding and decoding.

Character translation tables are great iff you're indexing by the character, not scanning and searching.

Other than that, the code above is too much of a mess to "fix". I think it needs a better overall design, so I'm reading further in *Craft of Text Editing* while writing new code.

Comment: [Updated code in new question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/176350/5912/termios-line-editor-for-apl-part-2)