# Arbitrary-dimensional arrays with transpose and slice

Tags: c, array, interpreter

This is the primary module for my APL interpreter. The general idea is motivated by my two [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023867/how-can-i-work-with-dynamically-allocated-arbitrary-dimensional-arrays) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409991/use-a-dope-vector-to-access-arbitrary-axial-slices-of-a-multidimensional-array), but the details I fear are easy to get wrong and I suspect there are a few corners that my eyes simply don't observe critically since they have the authority of having lain in the file so long without change.

The data elements here are always `int`s. "Everything is an `int`" was a guiding mantra in designing the whole project. So, via a tag/value encoding ([comp.lang.c code review thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.c/7NeTMCbl9zM/discussion) [newer code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/140994/5912)), values of many types can be embedded in these arrays. They're not *generic* in the normal C programming sense of the word. But by operating over `int`s, it achieves *genericity* by virtue of the way it is used by the other modules.

This code doesn't include garbage collection or any other lifetime tracking as I'm still figuring out how I want to do that. So these functions allocate their
results and expect the caller to manage freeing appropriately.

The [ppnarg.h](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/master/ppnarg.h) file provides counting of arguments in variadic macros. This is used to provide an easy interface to these functions. In order to create a [2][3][4] array, one calls.

```
array a = array_new(2,3,4);
```

The values can be accessed with the `elem` function which returns a pointer to the specified element, so that dereferencing the resulting pointer
is an l-value and can be the target of assignment.

```
*elem(a,1,1,1) = 'k';
putchar(*elem(a,1,1,1));
```

Various other function families like `slice*` and `transpose*` provide other superpowers by creating new *views* of existing data for which the `*elem()` function will index differently. One of my favorites is `cast` which lets you *hijack* an existing C array and wrap the dynamic header around it.

In order to generically iterate through the row-major order of any array requires the coordinated use of several of these functions, but I haven't packaged this into its own function. The different places where I have needed to do this haven't really factored nicely into a separate function.

```
// assuming `a` as defined above, will iterate through all 2x3x4 elements
int n = productdims(a->rank,a->dims);
int scratch[a->rank];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    vector_index(i, a->dims, a->rank, scratch);
    *elema(a,scratch) = 3;
}
```

`vector_index` returns its `scratch` parameter so the two functions can be composed into a single line. But it makes for a really long, unreadable line. At each stage, the *n-d coordinates* are available in the scratch array.

And my most recent augmentation is *function-type* arrays, which do not store all their declared data, but generate it as a function of the index. Thus, a [2][3][4] array of the constant `42` can be created without actually storing 24 `42`s in memory.

```
array b = array_new_function(3, (int[]){2,3,4},
    (int[]){1,42}, 2, constant);
```

`*elem()` for each index will return `42`. An array which simply consists of sequential integers `0`..`n` can be created with the `j_vector` function-type array. And a considerable degree of constant-folding can be done by modifying the elements of the `->weight` member array and the `cons` member. Indeed the values of any polynomial can be enumerated by creation of suitable dimension and weight parameters.

```
array c = iota(10); // function-type array generating 0..9 for indices 0..9
c->cons = 1; // generate 1..10 for 0..9
c->weight[c->rank-1] = c->cons = 2; // generate 2..20 by 2s
```

Do any spots look fishy? Or are there improvements I could make to the overall design or style or anything else?

[**ar.h**](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/6b7d3f1419aaf6cecd8e4845d31f713c3d23771b/olmec/ar.h)

```
#ifndef AR_H_
#define AR_H_
#include "../ppnarg.h"

typedef struct ar {
    int type;
    int rank;    // number of dimensions
    int *dims;   // size of each dimension
    int cons;    // constant term of the indexing formula
    int *weight; // corresponding coefficient in the indexing formula
    int *data;   // address of first array element
    int *(*func)(struct ar *,int); // data function (if function type)
} *array;

enum type {
    normal,
    indirect,
    function
};

int productdims(int rank, int dims[]);
array array_new_dims(int rank, int dims[]);
array array_new_function(int rank, int dims[],
        int *data, int datan, int *(*func)(array,int)); // type=function
int *constant(array a,int idx);
int *j_vector(array a,int idx);
void loaddimsv(int rank, int dims[], va_list ap);
array (array_new)(int rank, ...);
#define array_new(...) (array_new)(PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__),__VA_ARGS__)
array cast_dims(int data[], int rank, int dims[]); // type=indirect
array (cast)(int data[], int rank, ...); // type=indirect
#define cast(data,...) (cast)(data,PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__),__VA_ARGS__)
array clone(array a); // type=indirect
array copy(array a);

int *elema(array a, int ind[]);
int *elemv(array a, va_list ap);
int *elem(array a, ...);

int *vector_index(int ind, int dims[], int n, int vec[]);
int ravel_index(int vec[], int dims[], int n);

void transpose2(array a);
void transpose(array a, int shift);
void transposea(array a, int spec[]);
array slice(array a, int i); // type=indirect
array slicea(array a, int spec[]); // type=indirect
array slices(array a, int s[], int f[]); // type=indirect
array extend(array a, int extra); // type=indirect

array cat(array x, array y);
array iota(int n); // type=function
array scalar(int n);
array (vector)(int n, ...);
#define vector(...) (vector)(PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__),__VA_ARGS__)

int issolid(array a);
array makesolid(array a);

#endif
```

[**ar.c**](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/6b7d3f1419aaf6cecd8e4845d31f713c3d23771b/olmec/ar.c)

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "../ppnarg.h"

#include "ar.h"

int productdims(int rank, int dims[]){
    int i,z=1;
    for (i=0; i<rank; i++)
        z *= dims[i];
    return z;
}

// create new array object
array array_new_dims(int rank, int dims[]){
    int datasz;
    int i;
    int x;
    array z;
    datasz=productdims(rank,dims);
    z=malloc(sizeof*z
            + (rank+rank+datasz)*sizeof(int));

    z->type = normal;
    z->rank = rank;
    z->dims = (int*)(z+1);
    z->cons = 0;
    z->weight = z->dims + rank;
    z->data = z->weight + rank;
    memmove(z->dims,dims,rank*sizeof(int));
    for(x=1, i=rank-1; i>=0; i--){
        z->weight[i] = x;
        x *= z->dims[i];
    }

    return z;
}

// as a convention, a->data[0]==1
// indicating 1 (additional) data item (after data[0])
// data[1] is the actual data
int *constant(array a,int idx){
    return a->data+1;
}

int *j_vector(array a,int idx){
    a->data[1] = idx;
    return a->data+1;
}

// create special function-type array
array array_new_function(int rank, int dims[],
        int *data, int datan, int *(*func)(array,int)){
    int i,x;
    array z;
    z=malloc(sizeof*z
            + (rank+rank+datan)*sizeof(int));

    z->type = function;
    z->rank = rank;
    z->dims = (int*)(z+1);
    z->cons = 0;
    z->weight = z->dims + rank;
    z->data = z->weight + rank;
    memmove(z->data, data, datan+sizeof(int));
    z->func = func;
    memmove(z->dims,dims,rank*sizeof(int));
    for(x=1, i=rank-1; i>=0; i--){
        z->weight[i] = x;
        x *= z->dims[i];
    }

    return z;
}

void loaddimsv(int rank, int dims[], va_list ap){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<rank; i++){
        dims[i]=va_arg(ap,int);
    }
}

// create array, taking dims from variable argument list
array (array_new)(int rank, ...){
    va_list ap;
    int dims[rank];

    va_start(ap,rank);
    loaddimsv(rank,dims,ap);
    va_end(ap);

    return array_new_dims(rank,dims);
}

// create array object accessing existing array data
array cast_dims(int data[], int rank, int dims[]){
    int i,x;
    array z=malloc(sizeof*z
            + (rank+rank)*sizeof(int));

    z->type = indirect;
    z->rank = rank;
    z->dims = (int*)(z+1);
    z->cons = 0;
    z->weight = z->dims + rank;
    z->data = data;
    memmove(z->dims,dims,rank*sizeof(int));
    for(x=1, i=rank-1; i>=0; i--){
        z->weight[i] = x;
        x *= z->dims[i];
    }

    return z;
}

// create array accessing existing data taking dims from varargs
array (cast)(int data[], int rank, ...){
    va_list ap;
    int dims[rank];

    va_start(ap,rank);
    loaddimsv(rank,dims,ap);
    va_end(ap);

    return cast_dims(data, rank, dims);
}

// create a duplicate descriptor sharing array data
array clone(array a){
    array z=malloc(sizeof*z
            + (a->rank+a->rank)*sizeof(int));

    z->type = indirect;
    z->rank = a->rank;
    z->dims = (int*)(z+1);
    z->cons = 0;
    z->weight = z->dims + z->rank;
    z->data = a->data;
    memmove(z->dims,a->dims,z->rank*sizeof(int));
    memmove(z->weight,a->weight,z->rank*sizeof(int));
    return z;
}

// convert a ravel index to an index vector
int *vector_index(int ind, int dims[], int n, int vec[]){
    int i,t=ind, *z=vec;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        z[n-1-i] = t % dims[n-1-i];
        t /= dims[n-1-i];
    }
    return z;
}

// convert index vector to ravel index
int ravel_index(int vec[], int dims[], int n){
    int i,z=*vec;
    for (i=0; i<n-1; i++){
        z *= dims[i];
        z += vec[i+1];
    }
    return z;
}

// create a new array object with data copied from array a
array copy(array a){
    int datasz = productdims(a->rank,a->dims);
    array z=malloc(sizeof*z
            + (a->rank+a->rank+datasz)*sizeof(int));
    int i;
    int x;
    int ind[a->rank];

    z->type = normal;
    z->rank = a->rank;
    z->dims = (int*)(z+1);
    z->cons = 0;
    z->weight = z->dims + z->rank;
    z->data = z->weight + z->rank;
    memmove(z->dims,a->dims,z->rank*sizeof(int));
    for (x=1, i=z->rank-1; i>=0; i--){
        z->weight[i] = x;
        x *= z->dims[i];
    }

    for (i=0; i<datasz; i++){
        vector_index(i,z->dims,z->rank,ind);
        z->data[i] = *elema(a,ind);
    }

    return z;
}

// nb. cannot run on the ravel with non-solid indirect array
int *elemr(array a, int idx){
    if (a->type==function) return a->func(a,idx);
    else return a->data+idx;
}

int *elema(array a, int ind[]){
    int idx = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<a->rank; i++){
        idx += ind[i] * a->weight[i];
    }
    idx += a->cons;
    return elemr(a,idx);
}

int *elemv(array a, va_list ap){
    int idx = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<a->rank; i++){
        int ind;
        ind = va_arg(ap, int);
        idx += ind * a->weight[i];
    }
    idx += a->cons;
    return elemr(a,idx);
}

int *elem(array a, ...){
    va_list ap;
    int *z;

    va_start(ap,a);
    z = elemv(a,ap);
    va_end(ap);

    return z;
}


// elem(a,i,j) -> elem(a,j,i)
void transpose2(array a){
    int t;
    t = a->dims[0],
        a->dims[0] = a->dims[1],
                     a->dims[1] = t;
    t = a->weight[0],
        a->weight[0] = a->weight[1],
                       a->weight[1] = t;
}

// rotate indices by shift amount
void transpose(array a, int shift){
    int i;
    int t;
    while(shift){
        if (shift>0){
            t=a->dims[0];
            for(i=1; i<a->rank; i++)
                a->dims[i-1]=a->dims[i];
            a->dims[a->rank-1]=t;
            t=a->weight[0];
            for(i=1; i<a->rank; i++)
                a->weight[i-1]=a->weight[i];
            a->weight[a->rank-1]=t;
            --shift;
        } else {
            t=a->dims[a->rank-1];
            for (i=a->rank-2; i>=0; i--)
                a->dims[i+1]=a->dims[i];
            a->dims[0]=t;
            t=a->weight[a->rank-1];
            for (i=a->rank-2; i>=0; i--)
                a->weight[i+1]=a->weight[i];
            a->weight[0]=t;
            ++shift;
        }
    }
}

// select new order of indexing with array of dimension indices
void transposea(array a, int spec[]){
    int dims[a->rank];
    int weight[a->rank];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<a->rank; i++){
        dims[i] = a->dims[spec[i]];
        weight[i] = a->weight[spec[i]];
    }
    memcpy(a->dims, dims, a->rank*sizeof(int));
    memcpy(a->weight, weight, a->rank*sizeof(int));
}

// return new indirect array of one item of array
array slice(array a, int i){
    int rank = a->rank-1;
    array z=malloc(sizeof(struct ar)
            + (rank+rank)*sizeof(int));
    z->rank = rank;
    z->dims = (int *)(z+1);
    z->weight = z->dims + z->rank;
    memcpy(z->dims, a->dims+1, z->rank*sizeof(int));
    memcpy(z->weight, a->weight+1, z->rank*sizeof(int));
    z->cons = i*a->weight[0];
    z->data = a->data;
    return z;
}

// return new indirect array selecting a single item (if 0<=spec[i]<dims[i])
// or all items (if spec[i]==-1) from each dimension
array slicea(array a, int spec[]){
    int i,j;
    int rank;
    for (i=0, rank=0; i<a->rank; i++)
        rank += spec[i]==-1;
    int dims[rank];
    int weight[rank];
    for (i=0,j=0; i<rank; i++,j++){
        while (spec[j]!=-1) j++;
        if (j>=a->rank) break;
        dims[i] = a->dims[i];
        weight[i] = a->weight[j];
    }
    array z = cast_dims(a->data, rank, dims);
    memcpy(z->weight,weight,rank*sizeof(int));
    for (j=0; j<a->rank; j++){
        if (spec[j]!=-1)
            z->cons += spec[j] * a->weight[j];
    }
    return z;
}

// select a contiguous range from s[i] to f[i] of each dimension
array slices(array a, int s[], int f[]){
    int rank = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<a->rank; i++){
        rank += s[i] != f[i];
    }
    int dims[rank];
    int weight[rank];
    int j=0;
    for (i=0; i<rank; i++){
        while (s[j]==f[j]) ++j;
        dims[i] = 1 + (s[j]<f[j] ? f[j]-s[j] : s[j]-f[j] );
        weight[i] =    s[j]<f[j] ? a->weight[j] : -a->weight[j];
        ++j;
    }
    array z = cast_dims(a->data, rank, dims);
    memcpy(z->weight, weight, rank*sizeof(int));
    for (i=0; i<a->rank; i++){
        z->cons += s[i] * a->weight[i];
    }
    return z;
}

// prepend extra unit axes
// extend(vector(...),1) -> 1xN row vector
array extend(array a, int extra){
    int rank = a->rank + extra;
    int dims[rank];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<extra; i++)
        dims[i] = 1;
    memcpy(dims+extra, a->dims, a->rank*sizeof(int));
    return cast_dims(a->data, rank, dims);
}


// yield ravelled concatenation of two arrays 
array cat(array x, array y){
    int xsz = productdims(x->rank,x->dims);
    int ysz = productdims(y->rank,y->dims);
    int datasz = xsz + ysz;
    array z=array_new(datasz);
    int scratch[x->rank+y->rank];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<xsz; i++)
        *elem(z,i) = *elema(x,vector_index(i,x->dims,x->rank,scratch));
    for (i=0; i<ysz; i++)
        *elem(z,xsz+i) = *elema(y,vector_index(i,y->dims,y->rank,scratch));
    return z;
}

// generate a j-vector
// which yields iota values as a function of argument indices
array iota(int n){
#if 0
    array z = array_new(n);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        *elem(z,i) = i;
    return z;
#endif
    return array_new_function(1,&n,(int[]){1,0},2,j_vector);
}

// generate a 1 element vector, ie. a scalar array object
array scalar(int n){
    array z = array_new(1);
    *elem(z,0) = n;
    return z;
}

// create a vector array object initialized with variable arguments
array (vector)(int n, ...){
    va_list ap;
    array z = array_new(n);
    int i;

    va_start(ap,n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        *elem(z,i) = va_arg(ap, int);
    va_end(ap);
    return z;
}

int issolid(array a){
    int i,x;
    for (i=a->rank-1,x=1; i>=0; i--){
        if (a->weight[i] != x)
            return 0;
        x *= a->dims[i];
    }
    return 1;
}

array makesolid(array a){
    if (a->type==function || !issolid(a))
        return copy(a);
    return a;
}


#ifdef TESTMODULE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "minunit.h"
int tests_run = 0;

static char *test_basic(){
    array a = array_new_dims(1, (int[]){4});
    *elem(a,3) = 12;
    test_case(*elem(a,3)!=12);

    array b = array_new(4,5);
    *elem(b,3,4) = 5;
    test_case(*elem(b,3,4)!=5);

    array c = iota(4);
    test_case(*elem(c,3)!=3);

    //array d = iota(64);
    //array e = cast(d->data, 2,2,2,2,2,2); // no longer works with j_vector iota
    //test_case(*elem(e, 1,1,1,1,1,1) != 63);

    //array f = cast(d->data, 4,4,4); // no longer works with j_vector iota
    //test_case(*elem(f, 3,3,3) != 63);

    return 0;
}

static char *all_tests(){
    mu_run_test(test_basic);
    return 0;
}

int main(){

    char *result=all_tests();
    if (result != 0) {
        printf("%s\n",result);
    } else {
        printf("ALL TESTS PASSED\n");
    }
    printf("Tests run: %d\n", tests_run);
    return result != 0;

}

#endif //defined TESTMODULE
```

[**minunit.h**](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/6b7d3f1419aaf6cecd8e4845d31f713c3d23771b/olmec/minunit.h)

```
/* file: minunit.h
   cf.http://www.jera.com/techinfo/jtns/jtn002.html */
 #define mu_assert(message, test) do { if (!(test)) return message; } while (0)
 #define mu_run_test(test) do { char *message = test(); tests_run++; \
                                 if (message) return message; } while (0)

#define test_case(c) do { if(c)return #c; } while(0)

 extern int tests_run;
```

[GitHub](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/6b7d3f1419aaf6cecd8e4845d31f713c3d23771b/olmec)

Additional related modules have been posted for review [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115748/termios-xterm-line-editor-for-apl-interpreter) and in [comp.lang.c](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.c/X7BzyIKpogg/discussion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tangential request: Please pick useful (long if necessary) names for your source files. A very good start would be to take the "decoder ring" you posted to comp.lang.c and make the appropriate substitutions throughout.

```
ar ==> array
en ==> encoding
st ==> symbol_table
wd ==> scanner (or perhaps "lexer", if that's what you mean)
vb ==> verbs (or perhaps "operators", or perhaps "verbs_and_operators")
```

---

You're using `__VA_ARGS__`, so this must be C99 (or better). You should take advantage of C99's "declaration at point of use" syntax: i.e., instead of the K&R-C-looking

```
int productdims(int rank, int dims[]){
    int i,z=1;
    for (i=0; i<rank; i++)
        z *= dims[i];
    return z;
}
```

you should write

```
int product_of_dims(int rank, const int *dims)
{
    int z = 1;
    for (int i=0; i < rank; ++i) {
        z *= dims[i];
    }
    return z;
}
```

Notice that in addition to declaring `i` within the for-loop, I also

- `const`-qualified things that can safely be `const`
- added whitespace, for readability
- added curly braces around even one-line control structures, for consistency
- replaced `[]` with `*` in parameter declarations; `[]` is a misleading syntax, since what's being passed is *not* an array but merely a pointer.

---

I'll rewrite your next function, too, to show what it could be like:

```
array *new_array_with_dims(int rank, const int *dims)
{
    const int datasz = product_of_dims(rank, dims);
    struct array *z = malloc(sizeof *z + (2*rank+datasz)*sizeof(int));
    z->type = normal;
    z->rank = rank;
    z->cons = 0;

    z->dims = (int *)(z + 1);
    memmove(z->dims, dims, rank * sizeof(int));

    z->weight = z->dims + rank;
    for (int i = 0, wgt = 1; i < rank; ++i) {
        z->weight[rank-i-1] = wgt;
        wgt *= z->dims[rank-i-1];
    }

    z->data = z->weight + rank;

    return z;
}
```

From 23 lines (21 non-blank) to 21 (17 non-blank), and with a nice self-explanatory name (eliminating one additional comment line), *and* properly `const`-qualified.

I split up the initializations so that we conceptually initialize `z` first, then `z->dims`, then `z->weight`, and finally `z->data`. This isn't so much of a "good style" versus "bad style" thing; it was just a personal organizational choice.

---

Notice also that I quietly eliminated the confusing `typedef struct ar *array` in favor of `typedef struct array array`. Strongly prefer *never* to create an opaque typedef for a type that isn't a value type. The reader, being human, will instinctively assume that if he has an `array a` and creates a copy `b = a`, now he *has* a copy. If it turns out that what he really has is a *handle* to `a`'s data (not a new array at all), that's going to be frustrating to him.

Whereas, every C programmer can be expected to know that if you make a copy of `array *a` with `b = a`, you get a copy of the *pointer*. That's much more understandable.

If you are going to use typedefs for struct types, it's good style to write `typedef struct X { ... } X;` for every struct type in your program. That'll save the maintainer from having to look up for each type `X` whether he needs to be writing `struct X` or merely `X`; the answer is *always* "merely `X`". (The C++ language does this for you automatically.)

---

API design issue: You should avoid creating a pair of names `array_new` (macro) and `array_new` (function) that do different things. The Standard Library provides macro/function pairs such as `printf` and `isdigit`, but it always makes sure that the macro and the function have exactly the same semantics. You've made it so that `array_new(2,2)` creates a 2x2 array but `(array_new)(2,2)` segfaults. This is *very bad design*.

Call the helper function something like `array_new_helper` or `array_new_impl`, so that nobody will ever call it by accident (e.g., through a function pointer, or through a helper macro that wraps its arguments in parentheses for safety).

---

```
int t;
t = a->dims[0],
    a->dims[0] = a->dims[1],
                 a->dims[1] = t;
```

Looks like you need a function `void swap(int*, int*)`!
See also [Implement generic swap macro in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982348/). Writing three lines of code by hand every time you need to swap two values *will* bite you eventually, if you do it long enough.

---

I'm sure there's more to improve, but I'm out of time. This has probably given you a lot to go on, anyway.

Comment: Very useful stuff. I like the reorganized `array_new_with_dims` very much. For the swap example, I felt that it helped motivate the following function which uses the same idea in a more complicated way. *But,* that function is probably better implemented with 3 `memcpy`s and a temp array. ... I'm very much torn about the implicit pointer in the typedef. I feel it can greatly reduce the number of `*`s I need to type throughout the project, and it's limited to the 4 major abstractions (array, symbol-table, verb, abstract-number), but I at least should explain this convention in the README.

Comment: If "reducing the number of `*` in the source" is your goal, may I suggest Java? ;)  C (and C++) have a nice default convention that anything ending in `*` is a pointer/handle/reference type and anything not ending in `*` is a value type; breaking that convention is generally a bad idea. At least maybe change the names from `ar / array` to `array / arrayptr`? But then you're not saving any characters; you're just writing out `ptr` where I would have said `*`. And consider: if `typedef array *arrayptr;`, then what is the type of `const arrayptr p`? If you guessed `const array *`, you're wrong...

Comment: I have to concede that it may cause issues with `const`. I'm still learning how to use it. But for the rest, I think my specific setup makes this usage appropriate (or at least less inappropriate) than C code in the wild. eg [the tally function](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/c4584b0ea30c81277796b3408b936d5b14c328d3/olmec/vb.c#L211). The array is initialized with `array a = getptr(w);` and used with the `->` operator. So the fact that it's a pointer isn't hidden, but de-emphasized. ... But I know everyone probably says their own code should be the exception...

Comment: [latest commit](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/tree/fce42bcc033cd790726acef1095aa055bc52fdbb/olmec) reflects everything, I think, except the implicit pointer which I'm still hemming and hawing over... found/fixed a bug in `slicea` using `i` instead of `j`. ...Very pleased with these improvements. Thank you.