# Encoding data into integer handles for language interpreter

Tags: c, interpreter

As an integral part (pun intended) of my [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)) interpreter (previous questions: [1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98838/utf-8-encoding-decoding) [2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114243/unicode-capable-symbol-table-n-way-search-tree-with-hash-buckets) [3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115748/termios-xterm-line-editor-for-apl-interpreter) [4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122038/arbitrary-dimensional-arrays-with-transpose-and-slice)), this suite of functions converts any data into integer handles. APL operates on arrays of data cells, so with this encoding my cells are all `int` but may semantically contain other types. This enables me to have heterogeneous arrays with a homogeneous representation. Elements can even be arrays nested to arbitrary depths.

`common.h` contains definitions that are needed all over the place in the source. Some are not strictly relevant here, but the master `enum` of tags and the various implicit pointers, ie. `typedef struct verb *verb`, are important to be aware of. Hiding pointers in `typedef`s is questionable, to be sure. But I hope that the very short list of them compensates somewhat. `array`, `verb`, `xverb`, `symtab`, and `magic` are all (the) implicit pointers-to-struct types. I omit the contents of `../ppnarg.h` because it is not relevant here (but common enough to be `common`).

[common.h](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/85a9be7a7135e4f58bb3d4952f92fe97b2761b1c/olmec/common.h):

```
/*
 *  The central concept of encoding data is the use of the basic `int` type
 *  for "everything". We chop the 32 bits into an 8 bit tag[*] and 24 bit value.
 *  So we can't deal with literal numbers that are larger than 16.7 million 
 *  or so. 
 *
 *  An `int` which contains one of our encoded-integer values should be 
 *  declared `object` to convey this semantics to the reader.
 *  Conversely, having determined that an object's tag is LITERAL,
 *  code may feel free to treat it as a restricted-range integer value.
 *
 *  [*] since we treat negative numbers as encoding to themselves, in essence
 *  we only have a 7bit tag to play with.
 */

#ifndef COMMON_H_
#define COMMON_H_

#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../ppnarg.h"

#define MODE1(x) (x+(1<<7)) //add hi bit of ascii char

typedef int object;

typedef union integer {
    uint32_t uint32;
    int32_t int32;
} integer;

enum tag {
    LITERAL, /* val is a 24-bit 2's comp integer */
    CHAR, /* val is a 21-bit Unicode code point padded with zeros */
    PCHAR, /* val is a an executable char */
    MARKOBJ, /* val is irrelevant (s.b. 0) */
    NULLOBJ, /* val is irrelevant (s.b. 0) */

    LABEL, /* the statement number, counting from 1 */
    LPAROBJ,
    RPAROBJ,
    SEMIOBJ,
    RBRACOBJ,

FIRST_INDEXED_TYPE,
    NUMBER = FIRST_INDEXED_TYPE, /* val is an index in the number table */
    PROG, /* val is an (index to an) executable code fragment (array of PCHAR)*/
    ARRAY, /* val is a(n index to a) boxed array */
    SYMTAB, /* val is a(n index to a) symbol table */
    LBRACOBJ, /* val is an (index to an) array of the bracket contents */

    ANALYSIS, /* del function header info */
    MAGIC, /* get/set function pair */
    VERB, /* val is a(n index to a) verb object */
    ADVERB, /* val is a(n index to a) verb object */
    XVERB, /* val is a(n index to a) struct containing a verb and adverb */

    EXPR, /* val is a(n index to a) vector of the expression contents */
    BLOCK, /* val is a(n index to a) vector of expressions, a PROGN */
LAST_INDEXED_TYPE = BLOCK,
};

typedef struct array *array;

typedef struct verb *verb; // also used for adverbs
typedef object nilad(verb v);
typedef object monad(object w,verb v);
typedef object dyad(object a,object w,verb v);

typedef struct xverb *xverb;

typedef struct symtab *symtab;
typedef struct magic *magic;

#ifdef DEBUGMODE
    #define DEBUG(LVL,...) if (LVL<=DEBUGMODE) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
    #define IFDEBUG(LVL,...) do if (LVL<=DEBUGMODE) { __VA_ARGS__; } while(0)
#else
    #define DEBUG(...)
    #define IFDEBUG(...)
#endif

#endif
```

`encoding.h` declares a few singleton objects and the functions that are exposed. `init_en()` must be called before any other encoding functions.

[encoding.h](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/85a9be7a7135e4f58bb3d4952f92fe97b2761b1c/olmec/encoding.h):

```
#ifndef ENCODING_H_
#define ENCODING_H_
#include "common.h"

extern object null;
extern object mark;
extern object nil;
extern object blank;

void init_en();

int gettag(object d);
int getval(object d);
object newdata(int tag, int val);

object cache(int tag, void *ptr);
void *getptr(object d);
object getfill(object d);

#endif
```

And the implementation. For simple types, the `newdata` function constructs an encoded value by ORing the tag and value bits. For the pointer types, the `cache` function saves the pointer in a data bank structure (called `memory_bank`) and yields an index to be used as the value argument to `newdata`. The behavior depends upon the careful arrangement of the pointer type tags into a contiguous range so the tag number can be arithmetically manipulated to/from index values.

[encoding.c](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/85a9be7a7135e4f58bb3d4952f92fe97b2761b1c/olmec/encoding.c):

```
/*  Encoding
 *
 *  this file defines the sub-typing of data atoms.
 *  All data are packed into integer handles. The benefit for
 *  array operations is all data atoms will have a uniform
 *  size no matter what the content actually is. This replaces
 *  the intptr_t hackery (ab)used in earlier versions 
 *  (not portable to 64bit build). 
 *
 *  the array data are always just straight 32bit integers.
 *  but we treat as a 7bit tag and 24bit integer value.
 *  An immediate integer value is indicated by a negative
 *  sign-bit or all-zero tag. In essence, a 25bit sign/magnitude
 *  rep with no -0. This also means that we're not really using
 *  up all the available bits. Depending upon the final suite
 *  of distinct types and the desired "word size", this arrangement
 *  might be optimized further.
 *
 *  Composite objects (boxed or reference objects) have
 *  an associated pointer stored in an array associated
 *  with the tag. Thus an array object can be enclosed
 *  into a scalar (integer handle) with
 *
 *      int x;
 *      x = cache(ARRAY, array_new_dims(3,3)); //3x3 matrix
 *
 *  To better convey the abstract use of this integer type,
 *  we will make use of this typedef to designate such int-handles.
 *
 *  commont.h:
 *      typedef int object;
 *
 *  the array data structure (which is implicitly a pointer
 *  to its struct) can be retrived from the handle
 *  with
 *
 *      array a;
 *      a = getptr(x);
 *
 *  Most functions will need to check the types of their 
 *  arguments in order to determine how to proceed.
 *  This can be accomplished with `gettag()`.
 *
 *      switch(gettag(x)){
 *      case LITERAL: // handle atomic integer
 *          break;
 *      case ARRAY: {
 *          array X = getptr(x); 
 *      }
 *      }
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "common.h"
#include "encoding.h"
#include "array.h"

int gettag(object d){
    if (d<0) return 0; /* negatives are literals */
    integer int32;
    int32.int32 = d;

    return int32.uint32 >> 24;
}

int getval(object d){
    if (d<0) return d;
    integer int32;
    int32.int32 = d;
    return int32.uint32 & ((1U<<24)-1);
}

object newdata(int tag, int val){
    if (tag==LITERAL && val<0) return val;
    integer int32;
    int32.uint32 = ((unsigned)tag << 24) | ((unsigned)val & ((1U<<24)-1));
    int x = int32.int32;
    DEBUG(3,"newdata %x(%d %d)\n", x, tag, val);
    return x;
}

integer nulldata;// = { .data = { .tag = NULLOBJ, .val = 0 } };
object null /* = nulldata.int32 */;
integer markdata;// = { .data = { .tag = MARKOBJ, .val = 0 } };
object mark /* = markdata.int32 */;
object nil;
object blank;

void init_en(void){
    nulldata.uint32 = newdata(NULLOBJ, 0);
    null = nulldata.int32;
    markdata.uint32 = newdata(MARKOBJ, 0);
    mark = markdata.int32;
    cache(LBRACOBJ, array_new_rank_dims(0));
    blank = newdata(CHAR, ' ');
}

int addnewtocache(size_t *used, size_t *max, void ***data, void *ptr){
    if (*used == *max){
        *max = *max * 7 + 11;
        void *tmp = realloc(*data, *max * sizeof(void*));
        if (!tmp) return null;
        *data = tmp;
    }
    int z = (*used)++;
    (*data)[z] = ptr;
    DEBUG(3,"addnew %d %p %p\n", z, ptr, (*data)[z]);
    return z;
}


struct memory_bank {
    size_t used, max;
    void **tab;
} memory_bank[LAST_INDEXED_TYPE - FIRST_INDEXED_TYPE + 1];

object cache(int tag, void *ptr){
    if (tag < FIRST_INDEXED_TYPE || tag > LAST_INDEXED_TYPE)
        return null;
    int idx = tag - FIRST_INDEXED_TYPE;
    return newdata(tag,
            addnewtocache(&memory_bank[idx].used,
                          &memory_bank[idx].max,
                          &memory_bank[idx].tab,
                          ptr));
}

void *getptr(object d){
    if (d<0) return NULL;
    int tag = gettag(d);
    if (tag < FIRST_INDEXED_TYPE || tag > LAST_INDEXED_TYPE)
        return NULL;
    int idx = tag - FIRST_INDEXED_TYPE;
    return memory_bank[idx].tab[getval(d)];
}


// fill returns a "blank" value for any type
// and identity elements for verbs
object getfill(object d){
    switch(gettag(d)){
        case PCHAR:
            switch(getval(d)){
            case '+':
                              return 0;
            case 0x00d7:  // Times
            case 0x00f7:  // Divided-By
            case '*':
                 return 1;
            } /*fallthru*/
        default:
        case LITERAL:
            return newdata(CHAR, 0x2300); //null
            return newdata(CHAR, 0x2316); //position
            return newdata(CHAR, 0x2218); //jot
            //return newdata(LITERAL, (1<<24)-1);
        case CHAR: return newdata(CHAR, ' ');
    }
}
```

Additional referenced files from the same commit: [array.h](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/85a9be7a7135e4f58bb3d4952f92fe97b2761b1c/olmec/array.h) [../ppnarg.h](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/85a9be7a7135e4f58bb3d4952f92fe97b2761b1c/ppnarg.h). See my [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409991/use-a-dope-vector-to-access-arbitrary-axial-slices-of-a-multidimensional-array) for an in-depth explanation of the array code. `../ppnarg.h` implements a macro which counts how many arguments it was called with. This is used to provide variadic constructors for the array type. It's a wonderous little macro that should be part of everyone's cpp arsenal, but I didn't write it.

Any problem spots or infelicities? Any "too clever" spots?

I fear I may have made it difficult to design a garbage collector since my allocations are scattered all over this "data bank". It doesn't lend itself to a generational collector or a copying collector, and even mark-sweep will leave unused handles unless there's an extra free-list just for handles. Is there a better way to design my data bank to make it easier to scan for garbage?

Comment: For `reference: Wiki note [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language))

Comment: [comp.lang.c](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c/2etNwzYLB2M) meta-discussion of my GC obsession with this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any problem spots or infelicities? Any "too clever" spots?

Overall: Recommend to not causally mix `int/unsigned`, `int32_t/uint32_t`  and `size_t`.  Too many cases where code would fail by using both pairs.  Suggest using `int/unsigned` instead of `int32_t/uint32_t` with a `#if INT_MAX >= 2147483647` test.  (or fix/test the casual conversions.)

1. Disagree with not detailing `../ppnarg.h`.  If the contents of `../ppnarg.h` are common enough to be *common*, why is not `common.h` also considered common enough to be not posted?  Lacking this tile, a review cannot completely compile the code.  Without compilation, automated tools are prevented from use.  Without automated tools, this review request becomes unnecessarily extra burdensome.
2. `common.h` is too common.  Consider your successful code being used on a larger effort.  Perhaps `APL_common.h`.?
3. What/where is `#include "array.h"`?
4. "retrived" --> "retrieved"
5. Unclear double fallthru with the comment `/*fallthru*/` at the end of a switch statement.  It *appears* to apply to the `case PCHAR:` which then falls though to the `default:`  Strange to see a `case` after `default`.  Code uses a  `/*fallthru*/` comment there but lacks 2 such comments after `case 0x00d7:` and `case 0x00f7:`.  This inconsistent style confuses.  Top level `switch/case` indents the `case`.  Nested `switch/case` does **not** indent the `case`.  Inconsistent style unnecessarily confuses the review.  This implies OP is not using automated formatting.  Coding styles that depend on manual formatting are high maintenance.  Use an automated formatter.

   ```
   switch(gettag(d)){
       case PCHAR:
           switch(getval(d)){
           case '+':
                             return 0;
           case 0x00d7:  // Times
           case 0x00f7:  // Divided-By
           case '*':
                return 1;
           } /*fallthru*/
       default:
       case LITERAL:
   ```
6. Incomplete prototype declaration.  Using `()` allows following code to wrongly pass parameters and the compiler does not warn.

   ```
   // void init_en();
   void init_en(void);
   ```
7. Defeat of data abstraction.  `integer` does not imply size, bit of *some* size.  `int32` implies valuable is 32-bit.  I'd expect either 1) `integer` to be `integer32` if it is always going to be 32-bit or 2) if `integer` is abstract, `int32` have a name without an implied size.

   ```
   int gettag(object d) {
     integer int32;
     int32.int32 = d;
   ```
8. Possible data loss.  `d` is of type `object` (presently `int`) and `int32.int32` is of type `int32_t`.  This inconsistency should be resolved.  Recommend `typedef union integer { unsigned u32; int i32; }  integer;`

   ```
   int32.int32 = d;  // Potential narrowing of type.


   int getval(object d) {
     if (d < 0) return d;  // Potential narrowing of type.
   ```
9. Even discussing the type `array` and `struct array` is confusing in context with code that uses arrays.  Consider a different name.

   ```
   // typedef struct array *array;
   // Suggest
   typedef struct APL_array *APL_array;
   ```
10. Not a fan of using the same name for a type and `struct/union`.  Although these exist in different name spaces in C, they readily collide in a reviewers understanding.  Suggest `typedef struct APL_array_S *APL_array;`  or drop the typedef and only use `struct APL_array`.
11. Pedantic: Not portable when `int` < 24 bit.

    ```
    // int32.uint32 = ((unsigned) tag << 24) | ((unsigned) val & ((1U << 24) - 1));
    // more portable
    int32.uint32 = (unsigned) tag;
    int32.uint32 = (int32.uint32 << 24) | ((unsigned) val & ((1LU << 24) - 1));
    ```
12. Pedantic: Printing `int` values with `%x` outside the `[0...INT_MAX]` range is UB.

    ```
    int x = ...
    // DEBUG(3,"newdata %x(%d %d)\n", x, tag, val);
    DEBUG(3,"newdata %x(%d %d)\n", (unsigned) x, tag, val);
    ```
13. Possible loss of info in changing types.

    ```
    size_t *used
    ...
    int z = (*used)++;
    ```
14. The type name `object` misleads.  In C, an object can be a `struct`, `union`, `complex double`, etc.  Much code depends on `object` being a *real value*.

    ```
    void *getptr(object d) {
      if (d < 0) return NULL;
    ```
15. Adding common name to global space.  These will certainly collide on a large project.  Assume your good code will be re-used on larger applications.  Suggest putting all the following in a `struct` variable, maybe called `APL`.

    ```
    integer nulldata; // = { .data = { .tag = NULLOBJ, .val = 0 } };
    object null /* = nulldata.int32 */;
    integer markdata; // = { .data = { .tag = MARKOBJ, .val = 0 } };
    object mark /* = markdata.int32 */;
    object nil;
    object blank;
    ```

Comment: For point 1, I've added links to the files. Is that sufficient or should I inline them here?

Comment: I see what you mean in point 5, but I felt it was important to highlight the one fall-through that was *hard to see*, viz. when none of the sub-switch's cases are taken, and the outer case falls through to the default (which itself then falls-on-through to the next case). But all the other falls are easy to see by comparison. Perhaps I should add a `default: ; /*fallthru*/` to the inner `switch`?

Comment: For 14, instead of object, I've also considered `token`, `datum`, `atom` or `entity`. Is one of these better, or something else?

Comment: @luser droog How about `APL_object`?  I'm thinking of how to use your good code in the future with other code.

Comment: I do see your point about name spacing, but I have a strange resistance that I cannot seem to articulate. I really really like using the barewords because it makes the code more pleasant (for me) to read. I'd sooner maintain separate foo_external_interface.h files to provide mangled names if needed. .... But I wonder if there's a middle ground ....

Comment: @luser droog  Some type, variable, defines, helper function names can "hidden" with `static` and only declared in the *.c file.  Typically global functions and _the_ type cannot.  So their names need to be less common like `APL_data`, `APL_DoThis()`, `APL_DoThat()` ...  In term of making "more pleasant to read", recommend making the items in the `*.h` pleasant at the expense of items in the `*.c` file.  Those `*.h` items are what others use, (and you need to explain/document), not so much the `.c` contents.

Comment: I think the solution for 5 is to break it into 2 or more functions. It's just doing too many things.

Comment: @luser droog  Yes, breaking it up is some fashion would certainly help clarity.