# Termios line editor for APL - part 2

Tags: c, console, unix, unicode

This is the completely re-worked version of the APL line editor using termios raw mode.

[(Earlier version)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115748/termios-xterm-line-editor-for-apl-interpreter)

All `switch` constructs have been replaced with tables of function pointers to mirror the decoding of the UTF-8 character codes and vt2xx control sequences.

Part of the reason for tables instead of switches is for the possible eventual extension to allow the user to modify the editor dynamically, like an emacs.

The code also contains my latest code for the UTF-8 encoding and decoding ([earlier version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98838/utf-8-encoding-decoding)).

Any issues with the code?

ed.c:

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <stdint.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <termios.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <math.h> // log2 
//#include <sys/bitops.h> // ilog2 


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
// 
// UTF-8 <-> UCS-4 processing 
// 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

// type to contain 1 utf-8 "character" up to 4 bytes 
// if b[4] is 0, then b is a string 
// 
typedef struct { 
    int n; 
    unsigned char b[5]; 
} utfcp; 
uint32_t to_ucs4(utfcp c); 
utfcp to_utf8(uint32_t u); 

// Unicode-defined replacement for miscoded chars 
#define REPLACEMENT 0xFFFD 

/* number of leading zeros of byte-sized value */ 
static int leading0s(uint_least32_t x){ return 7 - (x? floor(log2(x)): -1); } 

/* number of leading ones of byte-sized value */ 
#define leading1s(x) leading0s(0xFF^(x)) 

// rather than signal an error, 
// we pass this through to allow for a special encoding 
uint32_t expand_shortcut(unsigned char b){ 
    return b; 
} 

uint32_t to_ucs4(utfcp c){ 
    int prefix = leading1s(c.b[0]); 
    int n = prefix? prefix: 1; 
    uint32_t u; 
    //printf("prefix:%d\n",n); 
    //if (n != c.n) 
    switch(prefix){ 
    case 0: u = c.b[0]; break; 
    case 1: return u = expand_shortcut(c.b[0]); 
    case 2: u = c.b[0] & 0x1f; break; 
    case 3: u = c.b[0] & 0x0f; break; 
    case 4: u = c.b[0] & 0x07; break; 
    } 
    //printf("%04x\n", u); 
    for(int i=1; i<n; ++i){ 
        u = (u << 6) | (c.b[i] & 0x3f); 
        //printf("%04x\n", u); 
    } 

    if (u < ((int[]){0,0,0x80,0x800,0x10000})[prefix]) { 
        //error |= over_length_encoding; 
        u=REPLACEMENT; 
    } 
    return u; 
} 

utfcp to_utf8(uint32_t u){ 
    if (u<0x20) return (utfcp){2, '^', u+'@'}; // sanitize control codes 
    if (u<0x80) return (utfcp){1,u}; 
    if (u<0x800) return (utfcp){2,0xC0|(u>>6), 
                     0x80|(u&0x3f)}; 
    if (u<0x10000) return (utfcp){3,0xE0|(u>>12), 
                       0x80|((u>>6)&0x3f),0x80|(u&0x3f)}; 
    if (u<0x110000) return (utfcp){4,0xF0|(u>>18), 
                        0x80|((u>>12)&0x3f),0x80|((u>>6)&0x3f),0x80|(u&0x3f)}; 
    //(else) error RANGE 
    return (utfcp){0,0}; 
} 


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
// 
// Terminal handling 
// 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 


struct termios saved_settings; 

void restore_terminal(void){ 
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &saved_settings); 
} 

void init_terminal(void){ 
    tcgetattr(0, &saved_settings); 
    atexit(restore_terminal); 

    struct termios raw_mode = saved_settings; 

    raw_mode.c_iflag |= IGNPAR; //ignore parity errors 
    raw_mode.c_iflag &=  //non-canon, no echo, no kill 
        ~(IGNBRK | PARMRK | ISTRIP | ICRNL | IXON | IXANY | IXOFF); 

    raw_mode.c_lflag &= 
        ~(ECHO | ECHOE | ECHOK | ECHONL | ICANON); 

    raw_mode.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB); 
    raw_mode.c_cflag |= CS8; 

    raw_mode.c_oflag |= OPOST;  //special output processing 

    raw_mode.c_cc[VMIN] = 4;  //min chars to read 
    raw_mode.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;  //timeout 

    if (tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &raw_mode) == -1) 
        perror("init_terminal"); 
} 

typedef struct { 
    unsigned unicode; 
    utfcp bytes; 
} character; 

// read up to 4 bytes from keyboard/stdin 
// and attempt to decode it as a utf-8 encoding 
// 
character read_character(void){ 
    int len; 
    char buf[5]; 
    do { 
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof buf); 
        len = read(fileno(stdin), buf, 4); 
    } while(len == -1 && errno == EAGAIN); 
    //printf("%d:", len); 
    //for (int i=0; i<len; ++i) printf(" %02x", (unsigned)(unsigned char)buf[i]); 
    //puts(""); 

    utfcp u = {len, buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3], buf[4]}; 
    return (character){ len==0 ? EOF : to_ucs4(u), u }; 
} 



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
// 
// The Line Editor 
// 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 


typedef struct editor { 
    unsigned *bufp; 
    int n; 
    unsigned *p; 
    int mode; 
} editor; 

typedef unsigned Decoder(editor*, character); 


void print(character c){ 
    if (c.bytes.n==1) 
        putchar(c.bytes.b[0]); 
    else 
        printf("%*s", c.bytes.n, c.bytes.b); 
    fflush(stdout); 
} 

void printbytes(character c){ 
    printf("%d:",c.bytes.n); 
    for (int i=0; i<c.bytes.n; ++i) printf("%04x ", c.bytes.b[i]); 
    fflush(stdout); 
} 

void store(editor *ed, character c){ 
    *ed->p++ = c.unicode; 
} 



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
// 
// Key Handlers (Decoders) 
// 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 


unsigned ignore(editor *ed, character c){ 
    return 0; 
} 

unsigned eot(editor *ed, character c){ 
    //printf("EOT\n"); 
    print(c); 
    character eod = { .unicode = 0x4, .bytes = { 1, 0x4 }}; 
    store(ed, eod); 
    return EOF; 
} 

unsigned bell(editor *ed, character c){ 
    printf("ding!\n"); 
    return c.unicode; 
} 

unsigned backspace(editor *ed, character c){ 
    if (ed->p > ed->bufp){ 
        printf("\b \b"), fflush(stdout); 
        ed->p--; 
    } 
    return c.unicode; 
} 

unsigned tab(editor *ed, character c){ 
    return c.unicode; 
} 

unsigned linefeed(editor *ed, character c){ 
    printf("linefeed\n"); 
    return c.unicode; 
} 

unsigned vtab(editor *ed, character c){ 
    return c.unicode; 
} 

unsigned formfeed(editor *ed, character c){ 
    return c.unicode; 
} 

unsigned carriage(editor *ed, character c){ 
    //printf("carriage\n"); 
    character nl = { .unicode = '\n', .bytes = { 1, '\n' }}; 
    print(nl); 
    store(ed, nl); 
    return '\n'; 
} 

unsigned shiftout(editor *ed, character c){ 
    return c.unicode; 
} 

unsigned shiftin(editor *ed, character c){ 
    return c.unicode; 
} 

unsigned nak(editor *ed, character c){ 
    return c.unicode; 
} 

// 
// The special APL keys accessed with ALT- or ESC+ 
// 
unsigned apl_alphabet[96] = { 
    //SP      !       "       #        $       %       &    ' 
    //    IBEAM DELTILD DELTASTIL DELSTIL CIRCSTIL CIRCBAR 
    ' ', 0x2336, 0x236b, 0x234b,  0x2352, 0x233d, 0x2296, '\'', 

    //  (        )       *       +       ,     -       .     / 
    //NOR     NAND CIRCSTAR DOMINO COMMABAR TIMES   ERGO SLASHBAR 
    0x2371, 0x2372, 0x235f, 0x2339, 0x236a, 0xd7, 0x2235, 0x233f, 

    //   0      1       2    3       4    5       6   7   
    // AND DIAERESIS MACRON      LT|EQ        GT|EQ 
    0x2227,  0xa8,   0xaf, '<', 0x2264, '=', 0x2265, '>', 

    //   8       9   :    ;      <     =     >     ? 
    //NOTEQ     OR              << DIVIDES  >> PILCROW 
    0x2260, 0x2228, ':', ';', 0xab, 0xf7, 0xbb, 0xb6, 

    //   @       A       B       C   D        E       F   G 
    //DELTIL _ALPHA_  EXEC    LAMP        _EPS_    SAME  DELTASTIL 
    0x236b, 0x2376, 0x234e, 0x235d, 'D', 0x2377, 0x2261, 0x234b, 

    //   H       I       J   K        L   M        N       O 
    //DELSTL   _I_  DIAJOT        'QUAD       FORMAT DIACIRC 
    0x2352, 0x2378, 0x2364, 'K', 0x235e, 'M', 0x2355, 0x2365, 

    // P      Q       R       S       T       U       V      W 
    //POUND inv?   REAL  SQUISH  TILSTL    NULL     PHI _OMEGA_ 
    0xa3,  0xbf, 0x211d, 0x2337, 0x236d, 0x2300, 0x2366, 0x2379, 

    //X     Y       Z       [       \       ]   ^       _ 
    //    YEN  SUBSTIL     <- BACKBAR      ->  BACKCIRC 
    'X', 0xa5, 0x2367, 0x2190, 0x2340, 0x2192, 0x2349, '_', 

    //   `       a       b       c       d       e   f       g 
    //DIAMOND ALPHA   BASE     CAP   FLOOR EPSILON        NABLA 
    0x22c4, 0x237a, 0x22a5, 0x2229, 0x230a, 0x2208, 'f', 0x2207, 

    //   h       i       j   k        l   m        n       o 
    //INCR    IOTA     JOT         QUAD       ENCODE    CIRC 
    0x2206, 0x2373, 0x2218, 'k', 0x2395, 'm', 0x22a4, 0x25cb, 

    //   p   q        r       s   t        u       v     w 
    //STAR          RHO    CEIL         DOWN     CUP OMEGA 
    0x22c6, '?', 0x2374, 0x2308, '~', 0x2193, 0x222a, 0x2375, 

    //   x       y       z       {   |        }   ~   DEL 
    //SUPER     UP     SUB    LEFT        RIGHT 
    0x2283, 0x2191, 0x2282, 0x22a3, '|', 0x22a2, '~', 0 
}; 

unsigned alpha(editor *ed, character c){ 
    c.unicode = apl_alphabet[c.bytes.b[1] - ' ']; 
    c.bytes = to_utf8(c.unicode); 
    print(c); 
    store(ed, c); 
    return c.unicode; 
} 

Decoder *metatable[256] = { 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 

    alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, 
    alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, 
    alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, 
    alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, 

    alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, 
    alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, 
    alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, 
    alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, 

    alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, 
    alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, 
    alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, 
    alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha, 

    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 

    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 

    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 

    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 

}; 

unsigned escape(editor *ed, character c){ 
    //printbytes(c); 
    switch(c.bytes.n){ 
        case 1: ed->mode = 1 - ed->mode; break; 
        case 2: ed->mode = 0; 
                return metatable[c.bytes.b[1]](ed, c); 
        case 3: ed->mode = 0; 
                // TODO 
    } 
    return 0; 
} 

Decoder *controltable[32] = { 
    //^@    ^A      ^B      ^C      ^D   ^E      ^F      ^G 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, eot, ignore, ignore, bell, 
    //^H       ^I   ^J        ^K    ^L        ^M        ^N        ^O 
    backspace, tab, linefeed, vtab, formfeed, carriage, shiftout, shiftin, 
    //^P    ^Q      ^R      ^S      ^T      ^U   ^V      ^W 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, nak, ignore, ignore, 
    //^X    ^Y      ^Z      ^[      ^\      ^]      ^^      ^_ 
    ignore, ignore, ignore, escape, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, 
}; 

unsigned control(editor *ed, character c){ 
    //printf("control character\n"); 
    //c.bytes = (utfcp){ 2, '^', c.unicode + '@', 0, 0 }; 
    return controltable[c.bytes.b[0]](ed, c); 
} 

unsigned ascii(editor *ed, character c){ 
    if (ed->mode){ 
        c.bytes.n = 2; 
        c.bytes.b[1] = c.bytes.b[0]; 
        c.bytes.b[0] = 27; 
        return escape(ed, c); 
    } 
    print(c); 
    store(ed, c); 
    return c.unicode; 
} 

unsigned extended(editor *ed, character c){ 
    return 0; 
} 

unsigned unicode2(editor *ed, character c){ 
    print(c); 
    store(ed, c); 
    return c.unicode; 
} 

unsigned unicode3(editor *ed, character c){ 
    print(c); 
    store(ed, c); 
    return c.unicode; 
} 

unsigned unicode4(editor *ed, character c){ 
    print(c); 
    store(ed, c); 
    return c.unicode; 
} 

Decoder *chartable[256] = { 
control, control, control, control, control, control, control, control, 
control, control, control, control, control, control, control, control, 
control, control, control, control, control, control, control, control, 
control, control, control, control, control, control, control, control, 

ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, 
ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, 
ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, 
ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, 

ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, 
ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, 
ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, 
ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, 

ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, 
ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, 
ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, 
ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, ascii, 

extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, 
extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, 
extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, 
extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, 

extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, 
extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, 
extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, 
extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, extended, 

unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, 
unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, 
unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, 
unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, unicode2, 

unicode3, unicode3, unicode3, unicode3, unicode3, unicode3, unicode3, unicode3, 
unicode3, unicode3, unicode3, unicode3, unicode3, unicode3, unicode3, unicode3, 

unicode4, unicode4, unicode4, unicode4, unicode4, unicode4, unicode4, unicode4, 
unicode4, unicode4, unicode4, unicode4, unicode4, unicode4, unicode4, unicode4, 
}; 


unsigned *read_line(char *prompt, unsigned **bufp, int *lenp){ 
    if (prompt) fputs(prompt, stdout), fflush(stdout); 
    if (!*bufp) *bufp = malloc( (sizeof**bufp) * (*lenp = 256)); 
    unsigned *p = *bufp; 

    character c; 
    utfcp u; 
    editor ed = { .bufp = p, .n = *lenp, .p = p, .mode = 0 }; 
    unsigned x; 
    do { 
        c = read_character(); 
        //printf("U%04x\n", c.unicode); 
        //printf("%*s", u.n, u.b); 
        x = chartable[c.bytes.b[0]](&ed, c); 
        u = to_utf8(x); 
        //printf("U%04x\n", x); 
        //if (x) printf("%*s", u.n, u.b), fflush(stdout); 
        //if (x) *p++ = x; 
    } while (x != (unsigned)'\n' && x != (unsigned)EOF); 
    *bufp = ed.bufp; 
    *lenp = ed.n; 
    p = ed.p; 

    if (p[-1] == EOF) p[-1] = '\n'; 
    if (p == (*bufp+1) && x == EOF){ 
        return NULL; 
    } 
    return *bufp; 
} 


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
// 
// main() 
// 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

int main(void){ 
    init_terminal(); 

    //printf("%u\n", (unsigned)'\n'); 

    char *prompt = "> "; 
    unsigned *buf = NULL; 
    int len; 
    while (read_line(prompt, &buf, &len)){ 
        for (int i = 0; buf[i]!='\n'; ++i) 
            printf("%04x ", buf[i]); 
        puts(""); 
    } 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: It this for  [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language))?

Comment: Yes, it's for APL. Thanks for the edit, @Jamal

Answer (score 2):

As for a review, remove the various uncommented code - it is a bit distracting.

Simplification in `uint32_t to_ucs4()` as below or replace `n` with `prefix`. `prefix? prefix: 1` only looks relevant to commented out code.

```
// int n = prefix? prefix: 1; 
int n = prefix;
```

Unusual code style

```
printf("\b \b"), fflush(stdout); 
// vs
printf("\b \b"); 
fflush(stdout);
```

Unclear why some apparently debug code remains and others are commented out.  Expect greater consistency.

```
unsigned linefeed(editor *ed, character c) {
  printf("linefeed\n");   // ** why is this here? **
  return c.unicode;
}

unsigned carriage(editor *ed, character c) {
  //printf("carriage\n");   // ** ...and  this commented out? **
  character nl = {.unicode = '\n', .bytes = {1, '\n'}};
  print(nl);
  store(ed, nl);
  return '\n';
}
```

Progressive use of *compound literals* - good.

Key Handler function names, being so short, should be `static` as they certainty are not needed out their source file - once code is segmented.

Expected `return (unsigned) EOF;`, `x == (unsigned) EOF` for consistency with `x != (unsigned)EOF`.

Cast `(unsigned)'\n'` not needed here as `'\n'` must be positive.

`p[-1]` is scary.  I did not deduce from code that this is *always* valid.  Hmmm.

---

More later if time permits.